# Identification Request: 10:4 pin cable

Tags: identification, cables, terminology

What are cables like this called?

[image]

(Bonus: what are the parts called?)

Answer (score 2):

I think the plug on the end is called a JST Connector - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JST_connector. I am not sure if a cable like that even has a unique name, looks pretty custom.

Comment: I believe there is a high chance you are correct about it being a type of JST connector. The specific terminology I was looking for might just be "harness". I googled "JST-EH" etc. and the two wire-to-board connectors with a 2.5 mm pitch seem to be the closest, judging from what I get on Google Images. Any chance you can narrow it down further than that?

Comment: The pitch is easy enough to measure it is just the distance between each pin, I think the tricky bit is sussing how how the plastic clip is connected, there are multiple companies that make these connectors and the are not all compatible so you just have to go through and look at the pictures on rs electronics or something similar if you want to find the corresponding male header.

Comment: Cheers. Didn't know about RS Electronics. I will see if I can find the exact connector there.